# How to convert text string (d h m s) to time format in excel

Tags: excel, formula

I have a column of data with the below format and need to convert it to a time format by hours to use in calculations and filtering like hh:mm for the first entry, no need for seconds

### 1d 8h 8m 23sm, 1h 10m 59s, 5m 54s

32:08, 01:10, 00:05

Tried some formulas but nothing helped me with this specific problem

Comment: use left() mid() right() with find() to get the detail and then join together, some examples exist on here. if() and iferror() to deal with absences.

Comment: Write an UDF (User-Defined Function) for this. I won't say that it's impossible in an Excel formula, but within one month you won't understand anything of it anymore :-)

Comment: "Tried some formulas" - Which ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may give a try to the following formula-

```
=LET(
d,IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(., 'd')]"),"d",""),0),
h,IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(., 'h')]"),"h",""),0),
m,IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(., 'm')]"),"m",""),0),
d*24+h&":"&TEXT(m,"00"))
```

If you do not have `LET()` function then try only `FILTERXML()`.

```
=(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(., 'd')]"),"d",""),0)*24)+(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(., 'h')]"),"h",""),0))&":"&TEXT(IFERROR(SUBSTITUTE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[contains(., 'm')]"),"m",""),0),"00")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked, I will finish my report then try to decrypt the formula :)

Comment: @TarekSaber Read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837697/5514747) by JvdV. This help you to understand `FILTERXML()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps using the following formula, it can be accomplished as is required:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=SUMPRODUCT(
    --(
        IFERROR(
            MID(
                0 & A1,
                SEARCH(
                    {
                        "d",
                        "h",
                        "m",
                        "s"
                    },
                    0 & A1
                ) - 2,
                2
            ),
            {0, 0, 0, 0}
        )
    ),
    {86400, 3600, 60, 1}
) / 86400
```

---

Or, Using one single dynamic array to spill:

[image]

---

```
=MAP(A1:A3,LAMBDA(x, SUMPRODUCT(--(IFERROR(MID(0&x,SEARCH({"d","h","m","s"},0&x)-2,2),{0,0,0,0})),{86400,3600,60,1})/86400))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

So using left() and mid():

[image]

Formulae:

Days as number of hours:

```
IFERROR(LEFT(A3,IFERROR(FIND("d",A3,1),0)-1)*24,0)
```

Hours as hours:

```
IFERROR(TRIM(MID(A3,IFERROR(FIND("d",A3,1),0)+1,(IFERROR(FIND("h",A3,1),0)-1)-(IFERROR(FIND("d",A3,1),0))))*1,0)
```

Minutes as minutes:

```
IFERROR(TRIM(MID(A3,IFERROR(FIND("h",A3,1),0)+1,(IFERROR(FIND("m",A3,1),0)-1)-(IFERROR(FIND("h",A3,1),0))))*1,0)
```

Seconds as minutes:

```
IFERROR(IF(TRIM(MID(A3,IFERROR(FIND("m",A3,1),0)+1,(IFERROR(FIND("s",A3,1),0)-1)-(IFERROR(FIND("m",A3,1),0))))*1>30,1,0),0)
```

For seconds I have included a brutal rounding of >30 is 1 minute. You can use it or not... so you can add them together or combine all in one cell, I left the detail of each so you can work out what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

This UDF (user-defined function), written in VBA, is not entirely correct, but it's a good start:

```
Function convertdate(r As Range) As String
Dim invoer() As String
Dim s As String
Dim days, hours, minutes, seconds As Integer
Dim i_d, i_h, i_m, i_s As Integer
Dim output, temp As String

temp = Replace(r, " ", "")
invoer = Split(temp, ",")
output = ""
For i = LBound(invoer) To UBound(invoer)
  s = invoer(i)
  i_d = InStr(s, "d")
  i_h = InStr(s, "h")
  i_m = InStr(s, "m")
  i_s = InStr(s, "s")
  
  If i_d <> 0 Then
    days = Left(s, i_d - 1)
  Else: days = 0
  End If
  hours = Mid(s, i_d + 1, i_h - i_d - 1)
  minutes = Mid(s, i_h + 1, i_m - i_h - 1)
  seconds = Mid(s, i_m + 1, i_s - i_m - 1)
  hours = 24 * days + hours
  
  If (output <> "") Then
    output = output + ", " + hours + "h, " + minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s"
    Else: output = hours + "h, " + minutes + "m, " + seconds + "s"
  End If
Next i

convertdate = output
End Function
```